# Can the Autobiographer badge be revoked?

Tags: support, badges

As this badge is awarded when a user fills all the details in his profile.

So does Autobiographer badge gets revoked if the member removes some field from his profile at a later stage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, regular badges are never revoked (unless one was earned fraudulently, in which case it takes a Stack Exchange developer to remove it). The Autobiographer badge is no exception, you get to keep it once earned.

Badges are there to teach you about features and encourage behaviour. It is fine if you learned about the profile feature some more by clearing it again.